# get values from Resources.Language.Resx and populate code behind fields WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, code-behind

I have the following code

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"  id="txtInternet" Foreground="Teal" FontFamily="Gill Sans MT" Text="{Loc Navigation_Panel_Title_Internet}" FontSize="30"  Height="45" Width="103" Background="White" />
```

In a WPF App, its great, but what I want to do is set the value for the text in the code behind. ?

Ie

```
 txtInternet.Text = {Loc Navigation_Panel_Title_Internet}
```

Anyone know how to do it ?

Im using http://wpflocalization.codeplex.com/ to change the languages

Comment: Why not use a [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

Try this method as mentioned [here](http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com/discussions/283041)

```
public string GetUIString(string key)
{
      string uiString;
      LocTextExtension locExtension = new LocTextExtension(key);
      locExtension.ResolveLocalizedValue(out uiString);
      return uiString;
}
```